# vim MRU plugin issue

Tags: vim

I have try to use MRU plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=521.
But when I type `:MRU` I got the following error message:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>10_MRU_Cmd..<SNR>10_MRU_Open_Window:
line 125
E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off:     $delete
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Does it happen all the time or only in some situations?

Comment: It's pop-up every time when typing :MRU command.

Comment: I don't experience that behavior. Try that: in the `mru.vim`, file, comment out line 770 (it should be `$delete`, you must turn it into `"$delete`), write the file and start another Vim instance.

Comment: or use an alternative plugin, like [Bufstop](https://github.com/mihaifm/bufstop), much faster and cleaner

Comment: FWIW, I had the same problem. The script worked fine for me for several months, and then abruptly started failing like this. I just ended up abandoning the plugin.